# Does beating hot oil into eggs before cooking an omelette make a difference?

Tags: eggs, omelette

Usually, when I prepare an omelette, I pour oil in a cast iron pan and heat it.
In the meantime, I prepare the eggs and I beat them fluffy. When the oil is pretty hot, I pour it in the eggs while beating them and finally I cook it in the pan.

As long as I can remember, I've done that following my mom's example. I assumed that it makes a difference but today my wife asked me why I was doing that.
I couldn't find an answer other than "I always do like that".

I'd like to know if this process have any value on the end result. If so, I could give her a better answer. If not, I will change my habits.

Comment: What kind of oil are you adding? Are you adding it as a flavoring or to keep the eggs from sticking to the pan?

Comment: I am using olive oil. But I don't know what is the purpose of that. Hence the question :)

Comment: In that case see my answer to come

Comment: @A.D. how much oil are you putting into how many eggs? I have to try this out!

Comment: What you're describing sounds like tempering (adding hot liquid slowly so it doesn't end up curdling) ... but I don't know if you're adding enough for it really to be a significant difference.  And the oil would affect how easily the proteins can link up ... so I would assume that you'd end up with more tender eggs.

Comment: @user110084 I don't know exactly. I eye-ball it every time, but I think it's about a table spoon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not tried or heard of this before. I can only arm-chair experiment in my head until I try this out. This seems to be an encapsulation/spherification method.

I can see a thin "shell" of cooked eggs coagulating around the hot oil droplets, trapping them and preventing separation. With many tiny beads of egg encased oil (effective oil buoyancy reduced) in suspension and thus more fats locked in the eggs there is likely a richer mouth-feel. This would not be achievable otherwise. Pretty neat trick. Your mom sounds like a modernist cook!

Comment: I like this idea :) Let me know when you try that.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to adding fat (for flavor and more silky eggs) I've seen this technique used used to temper cold eggs before adding them to the skillet.

*As to whether you should keep making eggs this way…* there are so many ways to cook eggs, I'd suggest that you keep trying new ways so that you have many options for preparing delicious eggs.

Personally, I prefer scrambled eggs beaten with some cream and cooked over low heat with a pat of butter.